# How to delete blocks of text which contain a specific string?

Tags: search, command-line, register, repeated-commands

I have a file which has the following structure

```
From: foo@example.org
Subject: Bar
Date: 2017-06-27
Mailbox: /some/dire/ctory
<CR>
```

Such a block always contains of four lines followed by an empty line. I want to delete all blocks which contain `Subject: Bar`. In the past I recorded keystrokes and replayed them. So I searched for the string (`/Subject: Bar`), hit `dap` and replayed it. This took quite a while for larger files. Thatswhy I'm looking for another approach.

How can I delete blocks of text in vim when they contain a search pattern?

Comment: I think this question can be rephrased as "How can I delete all headers from an email or mbox file?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a macro:

Once your search register is set to `Subject: Bar` you can empty a register (`q` in this example) and record the following macro:

```
qqq
qqndap@qq
```

The first line empties the `q` register, the second creates a macro like this:

```
qq           start recording
n            go to next match
dap          delete the paragraph
@q           call the macro recursively
q            stop recording
```

Then you simply need to play the macro once: `@q`

Or you could use a global command:

```
g/Subject: bar/norm! dap
```

Which means: for each line matching `Subject: bar` execute the ex command `norm! dap`